# Is the 2D canvas context on iOS Safari hardware accelerated?

Tags: html, canvas, webgl, hardware-acceleration

I am drawing a few polygons (no more than 10) in the browser with `canvas.getContext('2d');`, and have very bad performance on iOS. (The polygons only change in color)

My drawing function is very simple:

```
function drawTriangle(triangle) {

  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + triangle.color[0] + ',' + triangle.color[1] + ',' + triangle.color[2] + ')';

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(triangle.a.x, triangle.a.y );
  ctx.lineTo(triangle.b.x, triangle.b.y );
  ctx.lineTo(triangle.c.x, triangle.c.y );
  ctx.lineTo(triangle.a.x, triangle.a.y );

  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.fill();

}
```

I have profiled my app, and am 100% certain that the drawing in my canvas causes the slowdown (I have a steady 60fps without it, and it drops to 15-30fps with it, depending on the canvas size).

I am using `requestAnimationFrame`.

Do I need to use `.getContext('webgl')` to get better performance?

Comment: You can try, but using webgl is a lot more complicated. Your bottleneck is probably the all the ctx calls. They are SLOW. Try caching the triangles using another canvas and use drawImage instead.

Comment: I wonder how could caching could improve perfs : var col = triangle.color; var ta = triangle.a; var tb = triangle.b; var tc = triangle.c; And also remove the third lineTo, useless since you closePath. Notice also that string color conversion is slow : if you could precompute colors in the '#XXXXXX' format, that would surely help.